# jquery validation plugin

Tags: php, jquery, validation, forms

someone has used this jquery plugin for form validation?

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

i cant figure out how to use it. it doesnt say anything in the documentation how to name the html form elements to make it work with the validate() method.

and question nr 2, what php class validation is there to use for the server side?

EDIT: why doesnt this work:

```
$("#register_box_form").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        }

        email: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ?? Did you really read all of the documentation and tried out the demos (+sourcecode) on the plugin page http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ and all of them at the end of that page. I don't even understand what you mean by "how to name the form elements" they don't need any special name. Check out the demos and come back with more specific question when you tried out a few things. How you do your server-side is up to you. How does that relate to jQuery

Comment: apparently i have to add some predefined id values and class values to my form elements eg. 

<input type="text" id="cemail" name="email" class="required email" />

this will make it work with the plugin and it will automatically validate the email field. but i know this by looking in an example code. what are the other "metatags" i have to use to make it work with password, phone fields etc. where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="required email" />`, in this code, values for the class attribute 'required' and 'email' act same as the rules define in validate method in document ready function. That means `class="required email"` equals to,

```
email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        }
```

in above example.
I will tell what are the steps needed for including jquery validation. (you may already know each and every step) 
For use jquery validtion,
First you have to include main jquery library js file and jquery validation plugin js file.
Then on the document on ready function, you have to bind validate function to required form ( as mentioned in the example of above post).
You can either declare validation rules in this validate function or as values for class attribute of the relevant input element as I have described above.
Sometimes I have got problems when I use different values for id attribute and name attribute for input elements. I don't know the reason for it. So try to give the same values for id and name attributes and check if still validation not works.

You can use already included validation rules such as email, url, number, digit etc.
and also there is a rule called "remote" which can use for sending ajax request and do validation in server side.
In addition to that you can define custom rules according to your needs.
For example, I used following code to add custom validation rule for ensuring passwords are in correct password policy.

```
$.validator.addMethod("passwd_policy", function( value, element, param ) {
        return this.optional(element)
            || (value.length >= 8
                && /.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~]/.test(value) 
                && /[0-9]/.test(value)
                && /[a-z]/.test(value)
                && /[A-Z]/.test(value));
    },"Your password must be at least 8 characters long, <br/>contain at least one number, <br/>"
      +" at least one special character (!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_ ,~),<br/> at least one uppercase"
      +" character  <br/>and at least one lowercase character.");
```

You can add this custom validation method to validate a field as same as using inbuilt methods. that is like

```
   "txt_passwd": {
        passwd_policy: true
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  The documentation is not very clear about how to use a custom rule method within a compound rule list and this totally cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

You specify rules for the fields in the form. They are key/value pairs where the key is the name of the field.

E.g. a form with the fields *name* and *email* (from the documentation at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)

```
$(".selector").validate({
   rules: {
     // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
     name: "required",
     // compound rule
     email: {
       required: true,
       email: true
     }
   }
})
```

You can use the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html) for the php part. It has some [JQuery integration](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html), though not for the Validation plugin (yet?).

edit: In your example there is a comma missing between the two elements of your rules literal.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#register_box_form").validate( {
          rules: {
            name: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 3
            },
            email: {
              required: true,
              email: true
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="?" id="register_box_form">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" /><br />  
        <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont use zend framework. is there any stand alone php validation class i can download and use to validate the same way as this jquery plugin?

is this jquery plugin the best out there?

Comment: You don't have to use the whole framework to make the forms part available to you. But maybe http://docs.php.net/filter is something for you.